# Add additional key pair for authentication

Tags: key-authentication, ssh-keygen

I need to have a new key pair for an additional host that will be allowed to login to the server ( but I can't share the existing pair due to security reasons).

Now, I created a new pair on the server with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f newkey.key` which worked fine, I then copied they key to the client and try to login using `ssh user@server -i newkey.key` but it won't let me in, but instead I get:

```
$ ssh user@server -i newkey.key
Warning: Permanently added 'server' (ECDSA) to list ofknown hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
$
```

Why is this and how do I make this work? `newkey.key` has permissions set to `400`.

Comment: please see my edit to the answer... it is kinda important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most common issues I see when people try to set up key based authentication is that they forget to add the public half of the keypair to the `authorized_keys` file.

On `server.example.com` you generate the public/private keypair -

```
user@server:~/ $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -f newkey.key
```

Set password (or not) as appropriate.

Then put the public half into the `authorized_keys` file -

```
user@server:~/ $ cat ~/.ssh/newkey.key.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then copy the private half of the key to your client machine and you should be able to connect -

```
user@client:~/ $ ls -1 .ssh
authorized_keys
config
newkey.key

user@client:~/ $ ssh -i ~/.ssh/newkey.key user@server
```

**Edit** per @Haxiel and @RubberStamp (and my own) agreement that the private key shouldn't be left on the server it is used to access.

BE SURE TO REMOVE THE PRIVATE KEY FROM THE SERVER IT IS USED TO CONNECT TO unless you have no other alternative.  This is a security issue that is terribly easy to avoid.

Keys should be generated on the local machine and the public key copied to the remote machine via either scp or ssh-copy-id ... with the latter choice being preferred since it ensures that the public key is properly placed in the remote ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file along with the appropriate permissions on that file

Comment: Isn't this usually done the other way around? I mean, you'd generate the key-pair on the client machine, and then copy the public part over to the server you want to log in to. I'm curious as to why you would recommend this approach.

Comment: I agree with @Haxiel ... the private key should not be stored on an Internet facing machine unless absolutely necessary.  `ssh` keys should be generated on the local machine and the public key copied to the remote machine via either `scp` or `ssh-copy-id` ... with the latter choice being preferred since it ensures that the public key is properly placed in the remote `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file along with the appropriate permissions on that file... in any case, the private key should be scrubbed from the server once copied to local machine... `rm` or even better using `shred -n 5 -z`

Comment: @RubberStamp - I agree with you both - however the questioner specified that the key was being created on the server.